# How to get class type by its class name?

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

```
namespace Myspace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
} //This class is in another file.

using Myspace;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex regexViewModelKey = new Regex(RegularExpr.ViewModelKeyPattern);
    string viewModel = regexViewModelKey.Match(match.Value).Value;
    //Now, vieModel is a string, and its value is "MyClass". So, I only know the class name, this is why I ask this question.

    //Now, I'm only allowed to use the string form of this class name to get its type.
    //I have tyied like this, but its no use.
    Type t = Type.GetType(viewModel);
    //it's return a null.

    //Then I tyied another method like this, but there is an exception when calling Assembly.Load
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Myspace");
    Type ty = assembly.GetType("Myspace" + viewModel);
}
```

I hope my question is clear. Can any one help me.THX
I'm only allowed to use the string form of this class name to get its type.

thx everyone.
I have solved this question by myself like this.

```
{
      Type t = Type.GetType(string.Concat(viewModel, ",", "Myspace"));
}
```

Comment: maybe this'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045635/how-to-store-reference-to-class-property-and-access-an-instances-property-by-t

Comment: Try this way string model = "Myspace.MyClass";Use the assembly-qualified name instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648160/how-do-i-create-an-instance-from-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 60):

just use the function typeof(). The parameter is just that class name.

```
Type type = typeof(FIXProtoClientTest);
```

[MSDN on typeof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx)

Comment: Only if the type is known at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you'll hardly ever need to do type comparisons unless you're doing something with reflection or interfaces. Nonetheless:

If you know the type you want to compare it with, use the `is` or `as` operators:

```
if( unknownObject is TypeIKnow ) { // run code here
```

The `as` operator performs a cast that returns `null` if it fails rather than an exception:

```
TypeIKnow typed = unknownObject as TypeIKnow;
```

If you don't know the type and just want runtime type information, use the `.GetType()` method:

```
Type typeInformation = unknownObject.GetType();



     // int is a value type
    int i = 0;
    // Prints True for any value of i
    Console.WriteLine(i.GetType() == typeof(int));

    // string is a sealed reference type
    string s = "Foo";
    // Prints True for any value of s
    Console.WriteLine(s == null || s.GetType() == typeof(string));

    // object is an unsealed reference type
    object o = new FileInfo("C:\\f.txt");
    // Prints False, but could be true for some values of o
    Console.WriteLine(o == null || o.GetType() == typeof(object));

 // Get the type of a specified class.
                Type myType1 = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                Console.WriteLine("The full name is {0}.", myType1.FullName);
                // Since NoneSuch does not exist in this assembly, GetType throws a TypeLoadException.
                Type myType2 = Type.GetType("NoneSuch", true);
                Console.WriteLine("The full name is {0}.", myType2.FullName);

    // FileSystemInfo is an abstract type
    FileSystemInfo fsi = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
    // Prints False for all non-null values of fsi
    Console.WriteLine(fsi == null || fsi.GetType() == typeof(FileSystemInfo));
```

Comment: I have changed my question so that it's more clear.Could you see it again ? thx

Answer (score 3):

Your line Type.GetType(model) will work if you use the fully qualified class name, including its namespace.

Furthermore, if it's in a different assembly from the code that makes the call you should use Assembly.GetType(typeName) when the assembly object referred to is an instance of the assembly containing the type.